# Woocommerce conditional checkout fields and Eu VAT based on country and cart total

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

In woocommerce I have enabled Woocommerce EU VAT plugin and created a required custom checkout select field "Customer type" with 2 choices:

- Individual
- Business

Now I am trying to show and enable EU VAT field for:

- Orders amount up to `500` only
- `'customer_type'` for `'business'` only,
- Countries: **Denmark** and **Finland** only.

Here is my code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'add_eu_vat_to_checkout');

function add_eu_vat_to_checkout() {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || ! is_checkout() )
            return;

    $customer_type_value = WC()->session->get( 'customer_type' );
    $subtotal = $wc_cart->subtotal;
    $minimum_order_subotal = 500;

    if ($customer_type_value == 'Business' && $minimum_order_subtotal > 500)         
    {

        add_filter( 'woocommerce_eu_vat_number_country_codes', 'woo_custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes' );
        function woo_custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes( $vat_countries ) {
            // only show field for users in Denmark and Finland
            return array( 'DK', 'FI' );
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally no need of Ajax. Try the following (tested with WooCommerce EU VAT plugin):

```
// Add "Customer type" checkout field (For testing) - To be removed if you got it
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'add_custom_checkout_fields', 20, 1 );
function add_custom_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    // Get the "Customer type" if user is logged in
    if(is_user_logged_in() )
        $value = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'customer_type', true );


    $fields['billing']['customer_type'] = array(
        'type'      => 'select',
        'label'     => __('Customer type', 'woocommerce'),
        'options'   => array(
            ''              => __('Please, select your type'),
            'individual'    => __('Individual'),
            'business'      => __('Business'),
        ),
        'required'  => true, // required
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true,
    );

    // Set the "Customer type" if is not empty (from user meta data)
    if( ! empty($value) )
        $fields['billing']['customer_type']['default'] = $value;

    return $fields;
}

// Enabling Eu Vat for ('DK' and 'FI') when cart amount is up to 500
add_filter( 'woocommerce_eu_vat_number_country_codes', 'woo_custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes', 20, 1 );
function woo_custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes( $vat_countries ) {
    // HERE below your settings
    $countries = array( 'DK', 'FI' );
    $min_amount = 500;
    $cart_items_amount = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;

    // Avoiding errors on admin and on other pages
    if( is_admin() || WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        return $countries;

    // Show EU VAT field for cart amount up to 500 & users in Denmark and Finland
    return $cart_items_amount >= $min_amount ? $countries : array();
}


add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_jquery_script', 30, 1 );
function custom_checkout_jquery_script( $checkout ) {
    if( !is_checkout() ) return; // Only checkout
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        var a   = 'select[name=customer_type]',
            b   = 'business',
            i   = 'individual',
            bc  = '#billing_company_field',
            lbc = 'label[for=billing_company]',
            lr  = lbc + ' > .required',
            r   = '<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>',
            vat = '#vat_number_field';

        // On start (once DOM is loaded)
        $('label[for=vat_number]').append(r); // Mark Eu Vat required
        // Hide EU VAT if not business and other needed things
        if( b != $(a).val() && $(vat).length ) {
            $(vat).fadeOut('fast'); // Hide EU Vat field
            // If is an individual we hide company field
            if( i == $(a).val())
                $(bc).fadeOut(); // Hide company
        // Mark company field as required
        } else if( b == $(a).val() && $(vat).length ) {
            $(lbc).append(r); // Company required
        }

        // On "Customer Type" live event
        $('form.checkout').on('change', a, function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            // Show EU VAT and company For "business" with other needed things
            if( b == $(a).val() ){
                if( $(vat).length )
                    $(vat).fadeIn(); // Show EU Vat field
                $(lbc).append(r); // Company required
                $(bc).fadeIn(); // Show Company
            } else if( i == $(a).val()) { // For "individual"
                if( $(vat).length )
                    $(vat).fadeOut(); // Hide EU Vat field
                $(lr).remove(); // Remove Company required
                $(bc).fadeOut(); // Hide Company
            } else { // Nothing selected
                if( $(vat).length )
                    $(vat).fadeOut(); // Hide EU Vat field
                $(lr).remove(); // Remove Company required
                $(bc).fadeIn(); // Show Company
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}

// Update Order and User meta data for "Customer Type"
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'before_checkout_create_order', 20, 2);
function before_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) {
    // Set customer  type in the order and in user_data
    if( ! empty($_POST['customer_type']) ){
        // Update Order meta data for 'customer_type'
        $order->update_meta_data( '_customer_type', sanitize_key( $_POST['customer_type'] ) );
        // Update User meta data for 'customer_type'
        if( $order->get_user_id() > 0 )
            update_user_meta( $order->get_user_id(), 'customer_type', sanitize_key( $_POST['customer_type'] ) );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme)*. Tested and work.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this still works on the latest woocommerce storefront theme.

It would be more simplistic if we could just show the user the check box instead of drop-down bar asking **"Buying as a business?"** and if checked those two fields will appear. I changed the portion of the code but the Javascript has to be updated as well, hope someone can supplement it further.

```
    $fields['billing']['customer_type'] = array(
    'type'      => 'checkbox',
    'label'     => __('Checkbox label', 'woocommerce'),
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true,
);
```